# Matlab error "Find requires variable sizing"

Tags: matlab, find, matlab-coder

```
[~,col] = find(ocpRefPt(2,:)>x1 & ocpRefPt(2,:)<x2 & ocpRefPt(1,:)>y1 & ocpRefPt(1,:)<y2);
```

About is the line where the compilation fails. The above line is in a loop.
`x1`,`x2`,`x3`,`x4` are scalars(natural numbers)
`ocpRefPt` is a 2x16 matrix

```
Error: FIND requires variable sizing
```

What does this mean. How to overcome this error?

Comment: There's a little more information needed. What does ocpRefPt exactly look like (e.g. give an example)?

Comment: Printing the `size` of each thing would be my first step in debugging that.

Comment: ocpRefPt is a 2x16 matrix. But any ways I finally got to solve the issue. The problem was that the output was not a fixed size output which the compiler needed. the size was changing during runtime. I used a fixed matrix and it finally fixed the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it seems that you are trying to compile with `emlmex` to make embedded code.  The error is saying that the size of the output of `find` is not known, and apparently the compiler requires fixed size outputs.  See [this newsgroup post](http://newsgroups.derkeiler.com/Archive/Comp/comp.soft-sys.matlab/2009-03/msg01457.html) for one explanation.

This method of compilation seems to be obsolete -- use the [MATLAB coder](http://www.mathworks.com/products/matlab-coder/related.html) (`codegen` command) instead:

> `emlmex` Generate a C-MEX file from MATLAB code.
>
> ```
> emlmex [-options] fun1 [fun2 ...]
> ```
>
> This function is obsolete.  For general purpose acceleration
>       and code generation use `CODEGEN`.

Comment: Hey thanks a lot for the reply. I finally got it to work. You are right. The compiler needs a fixed size. As the size was changing at run time , it was erring out.