# ordfilt2: Find requires variable sizing

Tags: c++, matlab, image-processing, matlab-coder, vivado

I want to generate c++ code from the following Matlab function (Harris corner detection) that detects corners from an image.My constraint is that I have to generate a static library in C++ **without variable-sizing support**.
So, I have disabled variable size support from settings and also selected target platform as unspecified 32 bit processor.
In this way I'll be able to use it in Vivado HLS for an FPGA project.

However, when I generate the code, the line containing **ordfilt2** function throws an error that **FIND requires variable sizing**.

Please, help me if there is a workaround to this problem.I have seen a similar question posted here [Matlab error "Find requires variable sizing"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19369205/matlab-error-find-requires-variable-sizing) . But I am not sure how this applies to my case.Thanks.

Here's the code:

```
function [cim] = harris(im , thresh)

dx = [-1 0 1; -1 0 1; -1 0 1]; % Derivative masks
dy = dx';

Ix = conv2(im, dx, 'same');    % Image derivatives
Iy = conv2(im, dy, 'same');    

% Generate Gaussian filter of size 6*sigma (+/- 3sigma) and of
% minimum size 1x1.
sigma = 1.5;
g = fspecial('gaussian',max(1,fix(6*sigma)), sigma);

Ix2 = conv2(Ix.^2, g, 'same'); % Smoothed squared image derivatives
Iy2 = conv2(Iy.^2, g, 'same');
Ixy = conv2(Ix.*Iy, g, 'same');

cim = (Ix2.*Iy2 - Ixy.^2)./(Ix2 + Iy2 + eps); % Harris corner measure

% Extract local maxima by performing a grey scale morphological
% dilation and then finding points in the corner strength image that
% match the dilated image and are also greater than the threshold.

radius = 1.5;
sze = 2*radius+1;                   % Size of mask.


mx = ordfilt2(cim,sze^2,ones(sze)); % Grey-scale dilate.

cim = (cim==mx)&(cim>thresh);       % Find maxima.


end
```

[image: And here's the error]

Comment: You want someone to rewrite your code for you without using find?

Comment: No, I want a pointer on how to find a workaround.What really bewilders me is how the ordfilt2 requires variable sizing? and what exactly is find doing here.So, I can rewrite it myself.

Comment: You don't think it's the line with find() in it that is throwing the error?  `[r,c] = find(cim,100);`

Comment: No, the find here is not the reason.I have also edited the code to show what I actually used for code generation.